# Assigning values to std::vector<user-defined>

Tags: c++, c

I am working with images and computing radon transform for an object. The function that computes the transform accepts vector as input:

```
pixel p;
vector<pixel> segObj  //segObj is the object segmneted from the image
```

pixel is a user-defined struct defined as:

```
struct pixel
{
float x, y;  //x,y coordinates of the pixel
};
```

Currently, I am doing an element wise assignment to the vector:

```
for(int ix=0; ix < element_count; ix++)
{
f.x = xCoordArray[ix];
f.y = yCoordArray[ix];
segObj.push_back(f);
//xCoordArray and yCoordArray are computed separately
}
```

The for loop makes it slow when dealing with large images. Is there a way to assign `xCoordArray` and `yCoordArray` directly to `vector<pixel>segObj`

I am not expereinced with the use of vectors so any help would be appreciated.
Also,
If `xCoordArray`, `yCoordArray` can be computed as vectors, is there a way to join them so that each vector index as two values.

Comment: Have you tried with `segObj.reserve(element_count);` before `for`loop so that `vector` doesn't resize during insertion and the `push_back` becomes a constant time operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an input iterator producing `pixel` objects and assign those directly.  You could initialize the objects directly using something along the lines of this:

```
pixel iterator::operator*() const {
    pixel rc = {
        xCoordArray[index],
        tCoordArray[index]
    };
    return rc;
}
```

That said, I somewhat doubt that this is indeed the bottleneck: did you profile your code or are you suspecting that this is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

One reason of being it slow is the reallocation (and copy) done by the vector as the `for` loop executes. In your case, you could do this:

```
segObj.reserve(element_count); //DO THIS

for(int ix=0; ix < element_count; ix++)
{
  f.x = xCoordArray[ix];
  f.y = yCoordArray[ix];
  segObj.push_back(f);
}
```

This at least will improve the code a little bit, as there is one allocation before the loop, and no reallocation and copy is done when the `for` loop executes.

If your compiler supports C++11, then you could try this:

```
struct pixel
{
  float x,y;
  pixel(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) {}   //add this constructor
};

segObj.reserve(element_count); //DO THIS

for(int ix=0; ix < element_count; ix++)
{
  segObj.emplace_back(xCoordArray[ix], yCoordArray[ix]);
}
```

Note that it calls [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back), not `push_back`. This member function is available with C++11 only; it constructs the pixel objects in-place. No copy of pixel object is made when adding to the vector:

> `template< class... Args >`
> `void emplace_back( Args&&... args ); (since C++11)`
>
> Appends a new element to the end of the container. The element is constructed in-place, i.e. **no copy or move operations are performed**. The constructor of the element is called with exactly the same arguments, as supplied to the function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I am already using reserve, but there is little improvement when the number of pixels is > 2000. I would like to remove for loop but as each index has two values(x,y) it is not straightforward to use functions like .assign()

Comment: @user1291412:Even if you can use `assign` it would still be `O(n)` operation. I doubt whether this is the real bottleneck in your program.